# USB_CAM error : Input/output error

Tags: ros-kinetic, usb-cam, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to use web-camera(Logicool Webcam C210)

I use usb-cam package,but I cannnot see the web-camera view.

My launch file is below,

```
<launch>
  <node name="usb_cam" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node" output="screen" >
    <param name="video_device" value="/dev/video0" />
    <param name="image_width" value="640" />
    <param name="image_height" value="480" />
    <param name="pixel_format" value="yuyv" />
    <param name="camera_frame_id" value="usb_cam" />
    <param name="framerate" value="30" />
    <param name="io_method" value="mmap"/>
  </node>
  <node name="image_view" pkg="image_view" type="image_view" respawn="false" output="screen">
    <remap from="image" to="/usb_cam/image_raw"/>
    <param name="autosize" value="true" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

So,I got the error messages

```
[ERROR] [1536468451.681312829]: VIDIOC_S_FMT error 5, Input/output error
[usb_cam-2] process has died [pid 4954, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/usb_cam/usb_cam_node __name:=usb_cam __log:=/home/username/.ros/log/729b5ef0-b3eb-11e8-a98a-a44e31601874/usb_cam-2.log].
log file: /home/username/.ros/log/729b5ef0-b3eb-11e8-a98a-a44e31601874/usb_cam-2*.log
```

I have checked my device by command:

> v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext

I confirmed device number ,view size and pixel_format.

I tried other web-camera(logicool C270), but I got same error messages.

So, What am I wrong?

thanks.

(I use Ubuntu16.04LTS,ros-kinetic,and I installed [v4l-utils] and [usb-cam] packages)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302780/usb_cam-error-:-input/output-error/) by [takijo](https://answers.ros.org/users/36059/takijo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2018-09-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/39897/kiya/) on 2019-02-07**:
I have the same issue, someone please suggest different solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can solve this error by update ROS.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Thanks for your help.

---

Originally posted by [takijo](https://answers.ros.org/users/36059/takijo/) with karma: 110 on 2018-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/39897/kiya/) on 2019-02-07**:
This didn't work for me, can you suggest any other solution?

**Comment by [takijo](https://answers.ros.org/users/36059/takijo/) on 2019-02-07**:
Please up your code and error message.
and, make sure your  cam device number ,view size and pixel_format match the code again.

**Comment by [nana](https://answers.ros.org/users/37385/nana/) on 2019-04-15**:
Hello,
I have the same problem, do you solve it?